# Converting Query in Codeigniter format

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a query

```
SELECT        l.id,l.name,l.city,l.email,l.phone,l.status,l.source,l.leadCreatedTime,l.organizationId
FROM    (
    SELECT  id
    FROM    leads
where removed='0'
    ORDER BY
            id
    LIMIT 40000
    ) o
JOIN    leads l
ON      l.id = o.id
ORDER BY
    l.id
```

I want to convert this query in Codeigniter format for eg

```
$this->db->select('l.id,l.name,l.city,l.email,l.phone,l.status,l.source,l.leadCreatedTime,l.organizationId');
$this->db->from('leads');
```

Im having problem in the 8th line of query where the fetched data is defined as o how am I suppose to write that in CI

Comment: check with Codeigniter join

Comment: possible duplicate of [Codeigniter Active records complex query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214080/codeigniter-active-records-complex-query)

Comment: Why don't you check stackoverflow before posting the question? Duplicate of [Codeigniter Active records complex query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214080/codeigniter-active-records-complex-query)

Comment: It is not that question Rorschach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can u test my code it may help you as it is codegniter format

```
$this->db- >select('l.id,l.name,l.city,l.email,l.phone,l.status,l.source,l.leadCreatedTime,l.organizationId');
$this->db->from('(SELECT id FROM leads where removed="0" ORDER BY id LIMIT 40000) o');
$this->db->join('leads l', 'l.id = o.id');
$this->db->order_by('l.id');
$result=$this->db->get();
$show=$result->result_array();
```

it is not in fully codeigniter format in sub query but it help you.

Enjoy code.

Answer (score 0):

This May works for you:

```
$this->db->select('l.id,l.name,l.city,l.email,l.phone,l.status,l.source,l.leadCreatedTime,l.organizationId');

        $this->db->from('leads o');

        $this->db->join('leads l', 'l.id = o.id');

        $this->db->order_by("l.id", "asc");

        $q = $this->db->get();
```